# How to get rid of mold behind garage door railing

Tags: drywall, mold

Is this soot or mold:

[image]

The metal bar you see are the garage door railing. I'm looking up at the ceiling.

How do I get rid of this mold? Do I need to cut the drywall away? Or can I just spray it with something?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's mold. Spray some straight bleach on it.

Comment: damn. looks like it's on the surface for now?

Comment: It's really hard to say, but typically mold will lie on the surface, choosing the path of least resistance.

Comment: Hey @NPM Turned out not to be mold after all. It was residue from the garage-door chain ;)